# retrieving data from cloud firestore

Tags: java, firebase, backend

Hi im trying to retrieve values from a cloud firestore document in a collection based on a string query to filter the keys but cant seem to find any help online. Please assist or direct to existing solutions. Thanks. this is in java as well.

- I havent tried anything yet as I'm not too sure what functions provide this

im trying to filter a collection called food emissions with the key from this function

UPDATE

ive retrieved the data from the firestore collection and stored in a hashmap called food data. im now trying to filter this hashmap based on a string stored in the variable key and assign the value that matches to the variable co2EqTemp. however when I make a toast of the value thats stored in co2EqTemp it just says it is referencing a null value

```
        private void addMeal() {
            mealname =  mealName.getText().toString();
            if(mealname.isEmpty()){
                mealName.setError("Please name your meal!");
                mealName.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

            String UserID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            FirebaseDatabase fDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            fDbRef = fDatabase.getReference("MealLists");

            for(Map.Entry<String,Double> entry: food.entrySet()){

                key = entry.getKey();
                values = entry.getValue();

                foodAmount = values.toString();
                mealData meals = new mealData(key, UserID, foodAmount);
                fDbRef.child(mealname).setValue(meals);


                makeToast(mealname);
                 foodRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
                            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                                foodData.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
                            }
                            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: foodData.entrySet()){
                                if (entry.getKey().equals(key)){
                                    Co2eqTemp = (Double) entry.getValue();
                                }
                                Co2eq = Co2eq + Co2eqTemp;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                });


            }
            storeMeal();
        }
    });
```

Comment: First place to check is the docs. Can you post code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Phix posted the function im trying to retrieve all the values associated with the string stored in another collection called food emissions by the value stored in the key variable

Comment: so essentially have a where statement to filter the collection data based on the string stored in key

Comment: You say Firestore, but you're code for the Realtime Database. Show us your real database.

Comment: @AlexMamo ive just updated the code

Comment: I was referring to the database you're using, not the code.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I fixed this by just avoiding the hashmap completely and filtering the data returned from the collection like this.

```
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Map<String, Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
                            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()){
                                if(entry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                                    Double co2 = Double.parseDouble(entry.getValue().toString());
                                    Co2eqTemp = co2 * values;
                                }
                                Co2eq = Co2eq + Co2eqTemp;
                            }
                           
                       }
```